# Install roundcube, ubuntu server: IMAP NOT OK

Tags: roundcube

I'm trying to install mail server on my ubuntu server.

I'm comeing to step3 i'm trying to login to the smap (roundcube). got the error below

> IMAP connect: NOT OK(Login failed for postmaster@hvass7.com from
>   192.168.0.10. Wrong startup greeting (localhost:143): * BYE Disconnected: Auth process broken)

Can some one help me with this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i found it i edit inside (**vim /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext**)

i added (**driver = mysql**) to the file