# roundcube - Authentication failure

Tags: roundcube

i'm trying to craete a mail server in ubuntu server.

but i got this error here:

```
Trying to send email...
SMTP send: NOT OK(Authentication failure: SMTP server does not support authentication (Code: ))
```

Can some one help me with this?

Comment: This change might be related (commented for others who wants to help): https://superuser.com/questions/1467833/install-roundcube-ubuntu-server-imap-not-ok

Comment: i follow the guide here and it works for me :) (https://workaround.org/ispmail/wheezy/connecting-postfix-to-the-database)